# Many Subarray Sum Queries

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, sub-array

Subarray problem: Given integer array A (only positive numbers), is there a continuous subarray of any length with sum S? Sliding window solution to this is O(N).

Now if we have many such queries S on static array, we can do preprocessing. We can compute all subarray sums in O(N^2) and store them in a hash table. This also takes up O(N^2) space. Then we can process the queries in O(1) just looking up S from the hashtable

My question is, is there some O(N log N) prepeprocessing? Even if that means droping the queries to O(log N).

Comment: What is `Sliding window solution to this is O(N)` approach ? Have you fully specified the problem?

Comment: Do you fully understand the basic subarray sum problem that is well known?

Comment: That seems a bit difficult as to choose a sub array you will have to choose two indices ant that amounts to O(N**2)

Comment: @VinayakSingla intuitivelly it seems that it should be possible by clever augmentation of a segment tree no?

Comment: @Filip Nguyen There are some kinds of "subarray sum problem". Are all numbers positive? Is subarray length predefined? Does mentioned solution use O(1) of additional memory?

Comment: @Mbo I modified the question to include more information. All numberes are positive, the subarray length is not predefined it can be arbitrary. The known solution has O(1) - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum/

Answer (score 0):

> is there some O(N log N) prepeprocessing?

*No*.

There are N<sup>2</sup> possible subarrays in an array of size N. You cannot generate output of size N<sup>2</sup> in less than O(N<sup>2</sup>) time.

Comment: I dont require to generate N^2 hashtable using N log N preprocessing. The goal is that after *some* the preprocessing is done, it will be possible to query with at worst O(log N) time